# Floating div to go below partner

Tags: html, css

Consider the following `HTML` structure,

```
<div class='floated' id='div1'></div>
<div class='floated' id='div2'></div>
<div class='floated' id='div3'></div>
```

with the following `CSS`:

```
.floated {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#div1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}

#div2 {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;  
}

#div3 {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

This way, `#div1` will take up a 300px tall part of the left side of the page, while `#div2` and `#div3` will get floated to the right side of the page. How could I set up my `CSS`, so `#div1` and `#div2` takes up a single row(of height 300px, the maximum height of the two), and `#div3` will be placed right below `#div1`?

*I am not controling the height of these divs, this is dynamic, it is possible that sometimes the first one will be only 20 pixels, and the second one will be 1000 pixels, and the other way around is also a possibility*

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1u55fukj/

Comment: Can you not wrap the first two divs into a new one? `div` is non-semantic anyway, so you may as well use an extra `div` to make your life easier, assuming that you have access the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` on parent element (`body` in this case) and use `flex-wrap: wrap`. This will always make both `div`'s in same row equal height or equal to height of taller one [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/1u55fukj/2/)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.floated {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
#div1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#div3 {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='floated' id='div1'></div>
<div class='floated' id='div2'></div>
<div class='floated' id='div3'></div>
```

Comment: Upvoted this, this actually solves the problem, and if no other solution comes which is more compatible with a larger number of browsers, will accept it in a few hours! Thanks!

Comment: Is this how Bootstrap is making it's responsive design layout?

Comment: `Bootstrap 3` use `floats` but `Bootstrap 4` i think use `flexbox`

Answer (score 1):

If there will be only 2 divs in row, then you can try to give `clear:left` to `odd child`.

```css
.floated {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#div1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
#div3 {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
div.floated:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left
}
```

```html
<div class='floated' id='div1'>

</div>
<div class='floated' id='div2'>

</div>
<div class='floated' id='div3'>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a good workaround, but I would prefer a universal code, which supports more divs in the same row.

Comment: That's why I mentioned **If there will be only 2 divs in row** Then this will work.:)

Comment: So are you trying to have the _last_ element go below any preceding sibling, no matter how many there are before? `last-child` and `clear` property should do that.

Comment: @tmslnz no, what I want to achieve, is that if any x elements fill the complete width of the page, the next element should go to the next row, and by row, I mean a collection of x elements, with a height of the tallest element from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

flexbox is your best option i think.

you could use a div container and then use display flex

```css
.container{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.floated {
  width: 50%;
}

#div1 {
  height: 30%;
  background-color:red;
}

#div2 {
  height: 60%;
  background-color: green;  
}

#div3 {
  height: 40%;
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floated" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="floated" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="floated" id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

you can also center the 3rd div and a lot more :D. Flexbox have a good crossbrowsing support using -moz-, -webkit- etc,